# Using a group_by associaton to make multiple and very different operations

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that simulates purchases containing client's first names, second names, a paid amount and the item category of the item they bought.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'FirstName':['Peter','John','Peter'],'SecondName':['Jordan','Jackson','Jordan'],'Paid Amount':[1,4,6],'ItemsCategory':[1,2,5]})
```

Previously in my code I did the same multiple group by several times, trying to improve it.

The code should group by first and second name and calculate the following:

1. Get the total paid amount (a simple sum).
2. Generate a unique id (first name + last name + a random int).
3. Map each purchase to a category (using a dict, see code below) I map the category to 1/0 if the bought a belonging product.

   ```
       FirstName SecondName  Paid Amount  ItemsCategory
   0     Peter     Jordan            1              1
   1      John    Jackson            4              2
   2     Peter     Jordan            6              5
   ```

I am using the following dictionary to map the item ids to its category:

```
product_type={'healthPr':[1],'makeUpPr':[3,2]}
```

The desired output would be:

```
  FirstName SecondName     ClientID     TotalSpent healthPr makeUpPr
0     Peter     Jordan  PeterJordan-111      7        0         1
1      John    Jackson  JohnJackson-222      4        1         0
```

I got it working for the point 1,3 with the following code:

```
df_group = df.groupby(['FirstName','SecondName'])

 def get_total_paid(grouped_df):
    return sum(grouped_df['Paid Amount'])

 def get_products_by_type(grouped_df):
    final_series={}
    for k,v in product_type.items():
        cond_ = {k:''}
        if any(x in v for x in grouped_df['ItemsCategory']):
            cond_[k]= 1
        else:
            cond_[k]= 0
        final_series[k] = cond_[k]
    return pd.Series(final_series)

df_group.apply(get_total_paid)

df_group.apply(get_products_by_type)
```

For the point 2, get the ID it is a bit more complex because some customers have more than one entry per group conditions, I have to do the aggregation myself:

```
def get_customer_id(grouped_df):
    print(grouped_df)
    return f"{grouped_df['FirstName']}{grouped_df['SecondName']}-{random.randint(0,100)}"
```

Ideally I would like to have something like this where then I can keep adding my aggregations:

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(['FirstName','SecondName'])


calc_df = pd.Series({'CustomerID':grouped_df.apply(get_customer_id),
'TotalSpent':grouped_df.apply(get_total_paid),
'CategoriesBought':grouped_df.apply(get_products_by_type)})
```

But it is actually crashing because of the customerID, I want to avoid using lambda on the series as I want to do some exception catch (e.g name is empty string).

Comment: What happens to unmapped categories like `5` in the third row of the source frame?

Comment: @HenryEcker thanks for the point, they are ignored, item id 5 doesn't fit any category, so when it's mapped in function will not trigger any (int(any(.....)), at the end I end up with item categories from the dict. That part is working well, I am looking more for help in the get the user id and how to make it nice and testable (avoiding lambda x:)

Comment: [`aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#) might be what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend a different approach.

Create a mapper to [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) values in the `ItemsCategory` column from number to category and use [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) to encode into new columns:

```
# Replace Categories With Mapper
mapper = {v: k for k, lst in product_type.items() for v in lst}
df['ItemsCategory'] = df['ItemsCategory'].map(mapper)
# Expand Out Into Dummies (NaN will be dropped)
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['ItemsCategory'], prefix_sep='', prefix='')
```

`df`:

```
  FirstName SecondName  Paid Amount  healthPr  makeUpPr
0     Peter     Jordan            1         1         0
1      John    Jackson            4         0         1
2     Peter     Jordan            6         0         0
```

Then to get totals [`groupby sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) works:

```
# Groupby columns
g = df.groupby(['FirstName', 'SecondName'], as_index=False, sort=False)
df = g.sum()
```

For the ClientID, I'd recommend using [`np.random.randint`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) which can generate an array that can be concatenated with First and Second names:

```
# Add ClientID column using randint instead
df.insert(2, 'ClientID', df['FirstName'] +
          df['SecondName'] + '-' +
          np.random.randint(0, 100, len(df)).astype(str))
```

`df`:

```
  FirstName SecondName        ClientID  Paid Amount  healthPr  makeUpPr
0     Peter     Jordan  PeterJordan-81            7         1         0
1      John    Jackson  JohnJackson-45            4         0         1
```

---

Together

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'FirstName': ['Peter', 'John', 'Peter'],
                   'SecondName': ['Jordan', 'Jackson', 'Jordan'],
                   'Paid Amount': [1, 4, 6], 'ItemsCategory': [1, 2, 5]})

product_type = {'healthPr': [1], 'makeUpPr': [3, 2]}
# Replace Categories With Mapper
mapper = {v: k for k, lst in product_type.items() for v in lst}
df['ItemsCategory'] = df['ItemsCategory'].map(mapper)
# Expand Out Into Dummies (NaN will be dropped)
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['ItemsCategory'], prefix_sep='', prefix='')
# Groupby columns
g = df.groupby(['FirstName', 'SecondName'], as_index=False, sort=False)
df = g.sum()
# Add ClientID column using np.randint instead
df.insert(2, 'ClientID', df['FirstName'] +
          df['SecondName'] + '-' +
          np.random.randint(0, 100, len(df)).astype(str))

print(df)
```

Comment: that's some very good approach! I like the get dummies part a lot as well! But I would like to have everything like my last line, in one unique group to generate all the metrics by calling apply/aggregate as in the real code I have more operations, also makes the code more modular and testable in my opinion.

Comment: That's not possible with these types of metrics. Aggregate is limited to a single column at a time. `get_customer_id` would not work as you access 2 columns in the aggregation. The program design is not compatible with `pandas`. `groupby apply` is the only operation that allows access to multiple columns (at the cost of a single operation per apply). `groupby aggregate` is the only operation that allows multiple operations (at the cost of restricted access to a single column at a time).

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the answer, then you recommend looking into a mix of group_by apply and the other operations? I will give your answer for valid

Comment: While I agree with you that separate functions are easier to debug and follow. Often times in pandas they're extremely slow and the more obscure operations are much much faster. I'd recommend saving the grouper in a variable to avoid regrouping like I did `g = df.groupby...` Then do all the operations that can be done without it and separate values. I'd say this is the cost of the functions. Most line of code, separate operations, and CPU time. The benefits being easier to modify, debug, and refactor. That's the choice you'll need to make.